# android task manager clear memory

Tags: android, locationlistener

I run the application that contains the location listener, everything was fine and i did a **clear memory of the task manager** on my device, then i run back my app.

> LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
>   0, 0, locationListenerNetwork)

Quote code above never called until I do a restart my device and location listener back running normally.

GPS_PROVIDER called perfect, this happen only in NETWORK_PROVIDER

Anyone can explain why this is happen?

i run on my samsung galaxy s2 ics 4.0.3

Thank You.